# Fresh Lemon zest

Tags: baking

i baked a cake using fresh lemon zest. When the cake was done the cake had black speckles on the top and the bottom of the cake. Do anyone know why? Or how to prevent that from happening

Comment: Can you show a picture?

Comment: Hello and welcome! This question is almost good but a picture and a recipe would be helpful

Comment: How did you make the zest (grater, knife,.....?) What material was the baking dish made from (material and coating) and was it greased/papered/floured in any way? What baking temperature?